# How to create userinterface using my own libraries in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface

I want to create user interface using my own libraries and not a third part library like Qt, how is that called in C++. I would also appreciate any tutorials link on this stuff.

Comment: If you're looking for C++ articles or tutorials, SO's not the place. If you're looking for help with some native C++ code you've written, could you provide that and then the issue you're running into?

Comment: "*it was written in the website*" - what website?

Comment: If you don't want to use something like win32, your best bet is probably to write your own OS.

Comment: "..  companies like Microsoft and Apple use C++ for developing user interface in their OS .." well of course they had to create the GUI in *some* language. But as soon as they did, they didn't need to stick to the command line anymore. Just like modern C++ compilers are written in (you'd never guess) C or C++.

Comment: "... well of course they had to create the GUI in some language. But as...", i just wanted to know how exactly did they create using C++, what's it called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. There are [some proposals](https://msopentech.com/blog/2015/01/28/experimenting-with-a-proposed-standard-gui-for-the-c-language/#) for including GUI in the standard library, but none made it into the standard yet. You'll have to pick a third-party library for this.

Comment: Thanks Don Reba, so how are/were these third party libraries created(Just for knowledge).

Comment: @Sir.Geek, third-party libraries use OS APIs; OS APIs communicate with the graphics driver; the graphics driver communicates with the device using OS kernel services; and the kernel uses assembler. It's not "pure C++" at any level.